# Is there any historical evidence that suggest that Zoroastrianism is older than Judaism or vice versa?

Tags: religion, religious-history, judaism, zoroastrianism

So from what I remember reading around [Zoroastrianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoroastrianism) is or seems to be older than [Judaism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judaism) not only older, but the former seems to have influenced the latter. However while talking to a friend today he told me that that is not and that the dead sea scrolls actually seem to be evidence that Judaism is much older than Zoroastrianism?

I wanted to know if anyone here has the correct information or maybe reliable resources with that information?

Comment: Welcome to History:SE.  Perhaps you could edit your question to explain what more you are looking for beyond what is already covered in the Wikipedia articles on [Zoroastrianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoroastrianism#History) and [Judaism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judaism#History)?

Comment: From what I have read, various Dead Sea Scrolls date to varius dates between about 300 BC and about 100 AD.  I think that everyone already believed that Judaism began before 300 BC before the Dead Sea Scrolls were found, so I don't think that the Dead Sea Scrolls made Judaism seem much older.

Comment: Wikipedia is a good start. It's a complex question: by Judaism do you mean the religion of the Israelites at the time of Moses, or David/Solomon, or the codification around 500-600 BCE, or something closer to modern practice after the destruction of the Second Temple? Both Zoroastrianism and Judaism have their roots in ancient religious traditions, but you can't say "Judaism was created at X time", even in the way you can approximately date the founding of Islam or Christianity. (And of course it's possible for Zoroastrianism to influence Judaism even if Judaism is older.)